What's the purpose of alarm clock in soundproof underground hideout?
In A Quiet Place Part II (2021), I didn't understand the purpose of alarm clock in soundproof
underground hideout. If it beeps, then characters open the door.
What's the purpose of alarm clock in soundproof underground hideout?

The bunker is airtight.  The alarm tells them when to open the door to let fresh air in.

@DoscoJones that smells like an answer
